# IF statement in URL hack - what am I doing wrong

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

I have a URL hack which works fine, but I now need to insert an IF statement in to check for a null condition and use another field if so. What am I doing wrong here?

```
/500/e?
CF00NO00000029qLz={!Order.OrderNumber}
&CF00NO00000029qLz_lkid={!Order.Id}
&retURL={!Order.Id}
&RecordType=012O00000009PQf
&ent=Case
&cas4={!Account.Name}
&cas3={!IF({!Order.Therapist__c}=NULL,{!Order.CustomerAuthorizedBy},
{!Order.Therapist__c})}
&CF00NO0000002MGH0={!Order.EndUser__c}
&00NO00000029qMO=Customer
&00NO00000029qr2=1
```

Comment: do not use hardcoded ids

Comment: Where exactly are you using this code? VF page or custom button?

Comment: This is on a custom button - I need to populate a new Case from an Order, but can't save it at this stage as there are other fields to be entered first, that are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use **BLANKVALUE** function like this below in code :

> BLANKVAUE:
>   Determines if an expression has a value and returns a substitute expression if it does not. If the expression has a value, returns the value of the expression.

```
/500/e?
CF00NO00000029qLz={!Order.OrderNumber}
&CF00NO00000029qLz_lkid={!Order.Id}
&retURL={!Order.Id}
&RecordType={!$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomFieldName__c}
&ent=Case
&cas4={!Account.Name}
&cas3={!BLANKVALUE(Order.Therapist__c,Order.CustomerAuthorizedBy)}
&CF00NO0000002MGH0={!Order.EndUser__c}
&00NO00000029qMO=Customer
&00NO00000029qr2=1
```

Also, do not hardcode recordtype ids.

> Rather create a Hierarchy Custom Setting and access the value like this

```
RecordType =  {!$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CustomFieldName__c}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you just need to add in a couple of quotes to make the value being tested a `string` parameter to the `IF()`:

```
IF("{!Order.Therapist__c}"=NULL,"{!Order.CustomerAuthorizedBy}",
```

Comment: should only need one `!` in expression, no?

Comment: @cropredy Yep, good spot!